Why is coc-nvim adding an extra line?
I have the following mapping in .vimrc:
inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm() : "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"

Despite this, sometimes (not always) hitting enter autocompletes but adds a carriage return.  So if I hit <ENTER> to autocomplete to someThing:
        return <MyComponent someProp={someThi} />

I end up with
        someThing
        return <MyComponent someProp={someThing} />

and if I hit enter to autocomplete someThing.someOtherThing:
        return <MyComponent someProp={someThing.someOth} />

I get
        someThing?.someOtherThing
        return <MyComponent someProp={someThing?.someOtherThing} />

It also happens often when I'm doing console logs like:
console.log('hello, here's a long named thing: ', { thingWithAReallyLon })

turns into
thingWithAReallyLongName
console.log('hello, here's a long named thing: ', { thingWithAReallyLongName })

So I wonder if it has to do with clashes with a bracket pairing plugin, I'm using https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs

What is you disable auto-pairs? Do you still have the problem?

I have tried to reproduce your problem without success. Could you tell us in which filetype and with which LSP server (language and server) it happens?

Perhaps How to debug my vimrc
How to debug a mapping
are helpful?

@VivianDeSmedt yes seems like if I disable auto-pairs the issue goes away, thank you for your suggestion!

I'm in .tsx files, and I believe I'm using tsserver from coc-nvim

Thanks for your feedback I'll try to reproduce the problem on my end ;-)

https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/issues/346#issuecomment-1075292920  - this seems to resolve the issue at least as a workaround
